# Can bootstrapping angular at the end of body tag, make webpage slower than using ng-app on body tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

We were initially using ng-app on body tag. We have multiple modules working on the same webpage. It used to cause issues while specifying their Depedency injection. Creator of a module had to know the existing app and inject his app into the same.

we thought of manually bootstrapping all at the end of body tag together. Can it make things slower?

Given that angular is used to make some ajax calls and then update the UI.

Comment: doubt it would make much difference since most angular pages don't have much html in them to begin with ... until templates get loaded after bootstrapping

Answer (score 0):

Delaying the bootstrap of your app until the end of body may have some impact on the initialization of the app, but it should not be dramatic. Ultimately, it will depend on the overall complexity of your page.